# Generating a random number between two values

Tags: javascript

I need to generate a random number from 0 to the length of my array. This is my array

```
var wordList = new Array["duck", "cat", "dog", "carpet", "pants", "computer", "book"];
```

So basically, choose one of these words.
then I need to use that number to select that word and print it out.
Any help?

Comment: Should be from 0 to the length of your array - 1. Arrays are zero index based...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
wordList [ Math.floor (Math.random() * wordList.length) ]
```

**NOTE:**

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
>   number in the range [0, 1) that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not
>   including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired
>   range.
>
> The Math.floor() function returns the largest integer less than or
>   equal to a number.

1. [Math.floor MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
2. [Math.random MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

Comment: YOu should round this. Only integers make valid array indexes.

Comment: Ok, nevermind, you just added it ;)

Comment: You should `floor` this.  `wordlist[wordlist.length]` is undefined

Comment: @danronmoon or change `wordList.length` to `wordList.length - 1`.

Comment: @danronmoon thanks, I fogot to floor it